# Fuse + sshfs and OSX - cannot delete files

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sshfs, macos-catalina

Although I can create and rename files, for some reason I cannot delete files. I am mounting a UBUNTU 18 directory to OSX Catalina.

I have tried all sorts of combinations and used a different user too but nothing works.

```
sshfs root@example.com:/ /Users/myname/Desktop/remoteWebServer -oauto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,noappledouble,allow_other
```

When I do try to move the file to trash, I get error 8062.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a file to the Trash is not deleting a file.  When you delete a file, with the `rm` command or the `remove(2)` call, the file is immediately made inaccessible and its data is freed once no process has it open.  When you move a file to the Trash, the file is held in a temporary storage location (the Trash) until the Trash is emptied or the file is deleted from the Trash.

This matters because your SSHFS-mounted disk is a separate file system.  macOS normally stores your Trash contents in a file at the root of the drive, but in this case it can't do that, either due to permissions or due to the type of disk.

If you want to delete files on an SSHFS drive, use `rm`.  If that doesn't work, the error message you receive from `rm` will tell you what the problem is and you'll be able to figure out, using some Googling, what you need to fix based on that message.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files on mounted partitions does not work as @bk2204 already [pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/1534558/725976).

On the mac, you can delete files without sending it to trash by holding option+cmd+delete.